# AWS recover a deleted API KEY from API GATEWAY

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

**It happens that by mistake I have deleted an API KEY from API GATEWAY.**

I know that I can recover from API GATEWAY a method, let's say you delete a method POST or GET, and you Redeploy the stage you will have it back.

But, Is it possible to recover a deleted API KEY?, if yes, How to perform a recovery?. Cheers.

**UPDATE 1:**

After checking logs from AWS CloudTrail, I could find the event "DeleteApiKey" around the time of the mistake, however there is no "API KEY name" nor "String value" in those logs that help you identify the details of the API KEY, otherwise you would be able to rebuild the API KEY.

**UPDATE 2:**

**Contacted AWS Support**, passed the CloudTrail log hoping they could pull all the info I needed to rebuild the API KEY, however they said that because this resource “was outside of the 90 day history“, they didn't has any other info, just the same info from the log I have.

**UPDATE 3:**

I could recover the API KEY string from some Database. The name of the API KEY (didn't know the name) I recovered from AWS Config matching the CloudTrail log time. Finally the API KEY was rebuilt.

**CONCLUSIONS:**

- If you delete an API KEY it is not recoverable.
- AWS Support won't have much more info than you if the resource if more
  than 90 days old.
- If you have the API KEY string hard-coded somewhere like: code   itself or a Database, you will be able to rebuild it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For security purpose, there is no way to recover a delete API Key. You can Create a New one, Delete an other, or Update an existing key, but recover a deleted key, in my own, it's impossible.

You can just make a new one and update all you app using the deleted key with the new API Key.

Comment: @stdunbar Actually it is an API KEY from API GATEWAY which is a bit different than a "secret key", in any case thanks for trying to help.